# Проблема с заданием размера body html

Tags: html, css, html5

Пытаюсь задать размер body в 1366px width: 1366px;, но блок не растягивается на всю страницу, подскажите как решить данную трудность.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: что-то Вы не то делаете. зачем задавать размеры body?

Comment: @humster_spb т.к как по psd макету размер всей страницы 1366px при верстке страницы в 1920px все не совпадает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал обертку (.wrapper) для всего сайта в 1366px. И центрировал бы эту обертку.

```
<div class="wrapper">
 // а тут сам сайт.
</div>
```

в стилях пишем:

```
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1366px;
}
```

Comment: т.е я правильно понимаю что не обязательно отталкиваться от body достаточно указывать размер контейнера  в котором будет находиться все контент сайта?

Comment: Да достаточно указать размер контейнера. В боди можете общий цвет фона на всем экране поставить.